# Problem with Argument 2: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'UnityEngine.Transform'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I been working on this project on unity with youtube tutorial but i got some problems in code. This is my first project ever and i don't know any thing about coding. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlatformManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] _platformPrefabs;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; 1 < _platformPrefabs.Length; i++)
        {
            global::System.Object value = Instantiate(_platformPrefabs[i], new Vector3(0, 0, i * 12));
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Code is c++ and you have labeled as c#.  Object with two colons are c++.

Comment: Google difference between Transform and Vector3 and you will understand what's wrong.

Comment: @jdweng _"Code is c++ and you have labeled as c#. Object with two colons are c++"_ -  [incorrect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/namespace-alias-qualifier), it's for an aliased namespace, in this case the _global_ one.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) with two parameters which is only overloaded for setting the parent, a [`Transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html).

What you want to do is call it with three parameters and also pass a [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) for rotation. If you just want the default rotation, pass [`Quaternion.identity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-identity.html).

```
Instantiate(_platformPrefabs[i], new Vector3(0, 0, i * 12), Quaternion.identity);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Instantiate` is a function with many overloads, so it might not become apparent right away that the compiler expects something different than what you give.

In your case:

```csharp
Instantiate(_platformPrefabs[i], new Vector3(0, 0, i * 12));
```

you use two arguments which means that the override

```csharp
public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent);
```

is used.

You probably want to use:

```csharp
public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation);
```

which you can do in your code, by simply adding the `Quaternion.identity`, so that the offending line reads:

```csharp
global::System.Object value = Instantiate(_platformPrefabs[i], new Vector3(0, 0, i * 12), Quaternion.identity);
```